# Delphi and Excel - Using Autofill

Tags: excel, delphi, com, autofill

In Delphi 10 / Seattle, with Excel 2013... I am trying to:

- Add a Column (column AJ), and set its header text (code works)
- Set the value of the column, row 2, as an AutoSum (code works)
- Copy the calculation from row 2 to all remaining rows. (doesn't work)

During the 'Copy the Calculation' step, I am using AutoFill method.  I am getting an error 'Autofill Method of Range Class Failed.' but I don't know why... (note that variable aws is globally set the to the Active Worksheet.)

```
        const
        TOTAL_TOUCHES = 'AJ';
        ...

    var
            ColumnHeader : OleVariant;
            SecondRow    : OleVariant;
            ColRange     : OleVariant;
            myAddr, myAddr2 : String;
            LastCell : string;

begin
              // This routine adds the header 'Total Touches' and then puts an AutoSum in that column for all rows
              // Set the header
              myAddr := TOTAL_TOUCHES + '1';
              ColumnHeader := aws.Range[ myAddr, myAddr];
              ColumnHeader.FormulaR1C1 := 'Total Touches';

              // Put the first occurance of the Autosum in Row 2
              myAddr := TOTAL_TOUCHES + '2';
              SecondRow := aws.Range[ myAddr, myAddr];
              SecondRow.FormulaR1C1 := '=SUM(RC[-6]:RC[-1])';


               SecondRow.Autofill(aws.range['AJ3:AJ50', EmptyParam], xlFillCopy);
```

Once this is working, I will set this to copy to ALL columns in the row (as opposed to AJ3:AJ50, but this is a baby-step...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx) says the destination argument to `AutoFill`, which is the first argument, "must include the source range." In your case, the source range is AJ2, but AJ3:AJ50 doesn't include that cell.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks.